# How to automatically switch to HFP protocol after connecting to my Airpods?

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset, a2dp

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

When I connect my Airpods and try to use a conference application like Zoom, Teams or any tool of that sort, I always have to manually switch from **High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)** (i.e. marked as selected by the bullet-point next to it in the attached screenshot) to **Handsfree Head Unit (HFP)** (i.e. highlighted selection in the screenshot) to show my Airpods as an option in the available microphones list, so my voice would be transmitted through my Airpods microphone instead of the my laptop's microphone.

This gets much worse when the UI I use to switch those profiles isn't accurate or reliable sometimes.

Some of my colleagues don't have these issues while they're using the same version of Ubuntu. Is that because they're using a freshly installed version?
I remember I tried enabling my Airpods microphone when I used 20.04 and I suspect some of the configurations I applied before is causing this issue.

Is there a way to automatically switch to the valid protocol (i.e. HFP) when I connect my Airpods?
Or at least reset my audio settings if Ubuntu 22.04 already has this fixed out of the box?

[image]

Comment: It may be an idea to ask them what they did or look at their configuration.

Comment: I asked one of them and he said he did nothing! Let me ask the rest then.